# How to set time taken in "Seconds" while uploading file to move?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing MVC C# . I got a web page where user upload csv files. After uploading and saving data I write code to move the uploaded file to be moved with the same name to another folder in server,if another folder dont have means,we write code to create new folder. Now, the issue is, after move, if user immediately upload another file means the error message comes out "File Exists". My senior told me add seconds /milliseconds to the movepath file. Can anybody help how to add time?

my code is

```
string Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(loadPath);
            Name = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.csv", Name, SessionUtil.LoginUser.UserId, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmm"));
                        string MovePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Output, Name);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Output))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Output);
                System.IO.File.Move(loadPath, MovePath);
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(loadPath, MovePath);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmm")` to `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmmss")` ? So that if the user uploaded immediatelty, the filename wont be the same because of the seconds interval?

Comment: Or "ddMMMyyyyHHmmssfff" to include milliseconds too.

Comment: Yes. So that every time you upload a file, the name would be close enough to be unique because of the seconds interval.

Comment: This One Working Faster. I include ss only .thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your senior probably means for you to do something like this to burn a little time after the transfer (see the very last line):

```
string Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(loadPath);
Name = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.csv", Name, SessionUtil.LoginUser.UserId, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmm"));
string MovePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Output, Name);
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Output))
{
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Output);
}
System.IO.File.Move(loadPath, MovePath);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); // sleeps the thread for 250 msecs
```

**EDIT**

```
int sleepSeconds = 2;  // sleep for 2 seconds after moving file
string Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(loadPath);
Name = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.csv", Name, SessionUtil.LoginUser.UserId, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyHHmm"));
string MovePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Output, Name);
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Output))
{
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Output);
}
System.IO.File.Move(loadPath, MovePath);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepSeconds * 1000); // sleeps the thread for sleepSeconds seconds
```

Comment: Thank u so much can u plz explain the code and also for seconds like 1s,2s how to add?

Comment: Sure.  You can convert the number of seconds you need to pause the thread to milliseconds (what the `Sleep()` method takes as its parameter) by multiplying the number of seconds by 1000.  See edit to question.

Comment: thank you so much @STLDeveloper but I used @J Alc method, as it no nee do implement line or sleep ()

Comment: Ah- of course. I didn't get that the issue you were encountering was a filename collision.  Undoubtedly that's a superior solution.